# SQL Server Completion Percentage Category

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

im a bit new to sql server, so hopefully this isnt something too convoluted. if i have a table with a bunch of data that shows different records that have been complete or not...

TABLE 1

```
ID    CATEGORY    COMPLETE
1     reports     yes
2     reports     no
3     processes   no
4     processes   yes
5     reports     no
6     events      yes
```

...what would be the best way of creating a new field that would show the percentage complete for every category?

TABLE 2

```
ID    CATEGORY    PERCENTAGE
1     events      100%
2     processes   50%
3     reports     33%
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group by` category column and use conditional sum to get only `complete = 'yes'` cases in the numerator.

```
select category,
100 * 1.0 * sum(case when complete = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as pct
from tablename 
group by category
```

Comment: 1/2 = 0 Multiply by 1.0. Or use `sum(case when complete = 'yes' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)`

Comment: I would say that you would always get 0 or 100 from your query as you need to cast to decimal ..

Comment: just when i was about to post the change..thanks @lad2025

Answer (score 2):

You can use windowed functions and `PARTITION BY Category`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category,
[percentage] = ROUND(100 * SUM(CASE complete WHEN 'yes' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) 
                           OVER (PARTITION BY Category)/
                           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Category),0)
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402480)**</kbd>

With insert to second table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  [id] = IDENTITY(INT, 1,1)
 ,category
 ,[percentage] = ROUND(100 * SUM(CASE complete WHEN 'yes' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) 
                             OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY)/
                             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Category),0)
INTO #table2
FROM #tab
ORDER BY [percentage] DESC;

SELECT *
FROM #table2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402482)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach is to use `avg()`:

```
select category,
       avg(case when complete = 'yes' then 100.0 else 0 end) as pct
from tablename 
group by category;
```

If you want this as a number with a percentage, you need a bit more string manipulation:

```
select category,
       str(avg(case when complete = 'yes' then 100.0 else 0 end)) + '%' as pct
from tablename 
group by category;
```

However, I would recommend keeping the value as a number.